# What is wrong in my digital clock JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript

What is wrong in my digital clock JavaScript code?

```js
let digitalclock= () => {
    let now = new Date();

    let hour = now.getHours();
    let minute = now.getMinutes();
    let second= now.getSeconds();

    document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = hour;
    document.getElementById("minute").innerHTML = minute;
    document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = second;

    setInterval(digitalclock, 1000)

}

digitalclock();
```

```html
<div id="hours"></div>
<div id="minute"></div>
<div id="second"></div>
```

Comment: @mr.zeeshan your clock seems to work fine as far as I can see

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232219/discussion-on-question-by-mr-zeeshan-what-is-wrong-in-my-digital-clock-javascri).

Comment: "What is wrong in my digital clock JavaScript code?"—you tell us. What do you expect it to do? What is it doing instead? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Here you have an example how to make an clock with JS which uses the current time as starting time:

```js
var clock = document.getElementById('clock');

function time() {
  var d = new Date();
  var s = d.getSeconds();
  var m = d.getMinutes();
  var h = d.getHours();
  clock.textContent = 
    ("0" + h).substr(-2) + ":" + ("0" + m).substr(-2) + ":" + ("0" + s).substr(-2);
}

setInterval(time, 1000);
```

```html
<span id="clock"></span>
```